# Normal Normal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, bayesian

Two random variables where X ~ N(0,1) and Y|X=x ~ N(x,1) (Y is conditionally normal distribution given X=x).

I would to find the marginal distribution of Y.

I try to formulate f(x,y) = f(y|x)*f(x) and then I could do integration with respect to X.

However, I get stuck about how to do the integral with e^[(-1/2)*(y^2 - 2xy + 2x^2)] with respect to x.

Any hint would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that if we define $Z=X+G$ where $G$ is independent Gaussian zero mean and unit variance, then $Z$ has the same dependency on $X$ as $Y$ does.  That is, $Z|X=x \sim N(x,1)$.

Comment: If you want to integrate, it is a "completing the square" argument to get the integral itself to look like the integral of a Gaussian, which you know is 1.